# How do i go about writing a test class for this controller?

Tags: unit-test

I'm learning apex basics and deplying requires me to write a test class. Here's the controller..

```
 public class CalendarExample_Controller {

 public Boolean includeMyEvents {get;set;}
 public list<calEvent> events {get;set;}

 String dtFormat = 'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z';

//constructor
 public CalendarExample_Controller() {
    //Default showing my events to on
    includeMyEvents = true;
  }

  public PageReference pageLoad() {
     events = new list<calEvent>();
    //Get Contact's Birthdays
    for(Contact cont : [select Id, Birthdate, FirstName, LastName from Contact where       Birthdate != null]){
        //here we need to replace the birth year with the current year so that it will       show up on this years calendar
        DateTime startDT =       datetime.newInstance(Date.Today().Year(),cont.Birthdate.Month(), cont.Birthdate.Day());
        calEvent bday = new calEvent();

        bday.title = cont.FirstName + ' ' + cont.LastName + '\'s Birthday!';
        bday.allDay = true;
        bday.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
        //Because this is an all day event that only spans one day, we can leave the send date null
        bday.endString = '';
        bday.url = '/' + cont.Id;
        bday.className = 'event-birthday';
        events.add(bday);
    }

    //Get Campaigns
    for(Campaign camp : [select Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate from Campaign where                IsActive = true]){
        DateTime startDT = camp.StartDate;
        DateTime endDT = camp.EndDate;
        calEvent campEvent = new calEvent();

        campEvent.title = camp.Name;
        campEvent.allDay = true;
        campEvent.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
        campEvent.endString = endDT.format(dtFormat);
        campEvent.url = '/' + camp.Id;
        campEvent.className = 'event-campaign';
          events.add(campEvent);
      }

    //Get my Events if we have selected the correct option
      if(includeMyEvents){
        for(Event evnt: [select Id, Subject, isAllDayEvent, StartDateTime, EndDateTime      from Event where OwnerID = :UserInfo.getUserId()]){
            DateTime startDT = evnt.StartDateTime;
            DateTime endDT = evnt.EndDateTime;
            calEvent myEvent = new calEvent();

            myEvent.title = evnt.Subject;
            myEvent.allDay = evnt.isAllDayEvent;
            myEvent.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
            myEvent.endString = endDT.format(dtFormat);
            myEvent.url = '/' + evnt.Id;
            myEvent.className = 'event-personal';
            events.add(myEvent);
         }
       }
       return null;
   }

     public PageReference toggleMyEvents() {
      if(includeMyEvents){
        includeMyEvents = false;
      }
      else{
         includeMyEvents = true;
      }
       pageload();
    return null;
}


   //Class to hold calendar event data
    public class calEvent{
    public String title {get;set;}
    public Boolean allDay {get;set;}
    public String startString {get;set;}
    public String endString {get;set;}
    public String url {get;set;}
    public String className {get;set;}
   }
    }
```

Comment: There is more information on unit tests in general and a collection of links on the [unit-test tag wiki](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/unit-test/info) that are useful for finding more information about unit tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at this documentation here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm

But in short you will need to:

1. Create a test class and method
2. Insert into the database all the supporting data you expect the controller to retrieve.
3. Set the current page to be the VF page that the controller backs.
4. Instantiate an instance of the controller.
5. Call the pageLoad method to fire your logic.
6. Check the properties of the controller to ensure they contain the values you were expecting.